# Group conjugacy class $[x]$ and the centralizer $G_x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $x \in G$. The conjugacy class $[x]$ is also the adjoint-orbit $\mathcal{O}_x \equiv \{gxg^{-1} | \text{all } g \in G\}$. The centralizer of $x$ is then the stablizer subgroup $G_x$ with respect to the adjoint action.

We know that the elements of $[x] = \mathcal{O}_x = \{x_0 = x, x_1 = g_1 x g_1^{-1}, ..., x_{n-1} = g_{n-1}x g_{n-1}^{-1}\}$ are in one-to-one-correspondence with the cosets $G_x, g_1G_x, ... g_{n-1}G_x$. However, I'm curious about where the elements of $[x]$ sit with respect to these cosets. Here are some first thoughts.

0. $x \in G_x$.
1. Obviously, $x_i$ doesn't sit in $g_i G_x$, despite the correspondence. Otherwise, there exists a $g \in G_x$, such that $g_i x g_i^{-1} = g_i g$, which implies $g^{-1}x = g_i$; but this is impossible, since $g_i$ is not supposed to be inside $G_x$. However, $x_i$ must sit in some other coset $g_j G_x$. **Can two different $x_i$ sit in one coset?**
2. Also obviously, $x_i \in g_i G_x g_i^{-1}$. **But I wonder: are these mutually-conjugate subgroups $g_iG_x g_i^{-1}$ distinct? Do they "intersect"? If they intersect, are the $x_i$ the intersections?** ($g_iG_x$ are certainly distinct.)

Comment: 2. Note that $gG_xg^{-1}=G_{gxg^{-1}}$. Hence, the center of $G$ is contained in the intersection of the centralizers. In some cases $G_x$ is normal, so all the centralizers are the same.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Ah you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the Heisenberg group of order $p^3$, $p$ an odd prime,
$$G=\langle x,y,z\mid x^p=y^p=z^p=1, yx=xyz, xz=zx, yz=zy\rangle.$$
The center of $G$ is exactly $\langle z\rangle$, which is also the commutator subgroup, with $z=[y,x]= y^{-1}x^{-1}yx$. The group is nilpotent of class two, so the commutator bracket is bilinear.

An element $x^ay^bz^c$ commutes with $x$ if and only if $$1=[x^ay^bz^c,x] = [x,x]^a[y,x]^b[z,x]^c = [y,x]^b = z^b$$
which holds if and only if $p|b$. Thus, the centralizer of $x$ is $\langle x,z\rangle$.

A complete set of coset representatives is therefore given by $e$, $y$, $y^2,\ldots,y^{p-1}$.

So the conjugates of $x$ are precisely the elements of the form
$$y^{i}xy^{-i} = x(x^{-1}y^{i}xy^{-i}) = x[x,y^{-i}] = x[x,y]^{-i} = xz^i$$
with $0\leq i\lt p$.

All of these elements are in $C_G(x) = G_x$; so they all lie in the exact same coset of the centralizer.  So the answer to question 1 is "yes."

As Brauer Suzuki noted in comments, $g_iG_xg_i^{-1} = G_{g_ixg_i^{-1}}$, so the intersection is the centralizer of the subgroup generated by $[x]$. This always includes the center, so in many cases, this is nontrivial.

In the example above, it is precisely $\langle x,z\rangle = G_x$, because $G_x$ is normal (as it contains the commutator subgroup).

Comment: Very nice example, thanks!

Comment: @Lelouch: In fact, a group is nilpotent of class at most two if and only if each element commutes with all its conjugates (I was going to add that, but I want to figure out the precise conditions for there to be two elements of the conjugacy class in the same coset); in all such groups, the conjugacy class of $x$ is always contained in $G_x$. If $G$ is abelian this doesn't say much, but for any nonabelian group that is nilpotent of class two, this gives a nontrivial example. More generally, the conjugate $yxy^{-1}$ lies in $G_x$ if and only if $[x,y^{-1}]=[y^{-1},x^{-1}]$.